# Not off-topic as per your own list of requirements for posts

Tags: discussion, support, off-topic

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [Upgrade options for Cisco 6500 series](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/83021/upgrade-options-for-cisco-6500-series)

I have read your guidelines and no where in those guidelines does it say it has to be FOR an enterprise.  The equipment I'm using IS enterprise and was decommisioned from an enterprise where I work.  I am not asking for home level equipment suggestions to replace the enterprise hardware, I'm asking for suggestions for enterprise equipment to UPGRADE my existing enterprise equipment.  Again no where in your site guidelines does it say that the equipment has to be installed AT an enterprise.

Comment: I explained in the comment to the question that home networking is explicitly off-topic here, as are product or resource recommendations. Your question clearly conflicts with those criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but

- **operating, maintaining, purchasing or managing an enterprise / service provider network;**

clearly excludes home networks.

- **product or resource recommendations;**

are also explicitly off topic, regardless of home or enterprise networking.

Please check [What topics can I ask about here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details.